# VBA re-dimensioning array based on a loop

Tags: arrays, vba, preserve

I am trying to fill in an array but increasing the element size for dim 1 on each iteration, but am getting a "Subscript out of range message" when I try

```
ReDim Preserve sArray(1 To jTotal, 1 To UBound(sArray, 2))
```

Any ideas?

```
Dim j As Integer, jTotal As Integer
Dim eCount As Integer

ReDim sArray(1, 6)

For j = 1 To Application.Session.AddressLists.Item(AddList).AddressEntries.Count

    On Error GoTo Err

    If VBA.InStr(1, Application.Session.AddressLists.Item(AddList).AddressEntries.Item(j).GetExchangeUser.Department, _
    fFilter, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    jTotal = jTotal + 1

'    '--> Redimensioning the array
    ReDim Preserve sArray(1 To UBound(sArray, 1), 1 To UBound(sArray, 2))
    'ReDim Preserve sArray(1 To jTotal, 1 To UBound(sArray, 2))

    sArray(jTotal, 1) = j
    sArray(jTotal, 2) = Application.Session.AddressLists.Item(AddList).AddressEntries.Item(j).Name
    sArray(jTotal, 3) = Application.Session.AddressLists.Item(AddList).AddressEntries.Item(j).GetExchangeUser.Alias
    sArray(jTotal, 4) = Application.Session.AddressLists.Item(AddList).AddressEntries.Item(j).GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    sArray(jTotal, 5) = Application.Session.AddressLists.Item(AddList).AddressEntries.Item(j).GetExchangeUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber
    sArray(jTotal, 6) = Application.Session.AddressLists.Item(AddList).AddressEntries.Item(j).GetExchangeUser.Department

    If Err.Number > 0 Then eCount = eCount + 1

    End If

Next j
```

Comment: You can only resize the last dimension of an array.

Comment: FWIW you should probably declare the array with a known/fixed size from the start, instead of copying the entire array at every iteration; computing the size of the array before looping to populate it would probably perform better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888722/vba-re-dimensioning-array-based-on-a-loop/48888910#comment84782589_48888722), you can only resize the last dimension of an array (which is the second dimension in your example)

Also, watch out for this: `ReDim sArray(1, 6)`. It creates an array with dimensions **`(0 to 1, 0 to 6)`** not `(1 to 1, 1 to 6)`. So `Redim Preserve sArray(1 to 1, 1 to 6)` still won't work because you will be resizing the first dimension again.

Re-dimension your array something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sArray As Variant
    ReDim sArray(1 To 1, 1 To 6)
    ReDim Preserve sArray(1 To 1, 1 To 7)
End Sub
```

Comment: That works too, although I didn't mention it because I think it's better to explicitly state your base :)

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your code using Collection:

```
Dim sArray As New Collection
```

Add new elements with

```
sArray.Add(item)
```

You will never need to use redim with a Collection. It is handles automatically.
Google on *VBA Collection*  for additional info.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go now. I didn't realize there was a limitation to using Preserve keyword

Comment: Sorry Mike, did not accuse or suspect you. Just curious who outside you did.
Also Mike, if you know C++, a Collection is like a vector<item> in that language